# pipe from tar to ftp

Tags: backup, ftp, pipe

I have ftp access to a server I do not control. I'd like to start sending archives of my server's FS to that ftp. The problem is I don't have enough free space on my system to create a backup archive first (and store it on my fs) and then send it to ftp. So I'm wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

```
tar -jcpvf - / | ftp-put ftp://user:pass@host/file.tbz
```

Normally there is no problem doing it over ssh, but in this case I only have ftp available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [ncftpput](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html). Should be available for all major Linux distributions.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. I've found it in EPEL repository for my CentOS box.